# Updating values on NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'v run into such problem. I need to update the values in my NSArray. And don't know a way to do it. Here's my array

```
NSArray *arrayWithInfo = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:AMLocalizedString(@"Status", nil),AMLocalizedString(@"Call", nil),AMLocalizedString(@"Location", nil),AMLocalizedString(@"Control", nil),AMLocalizedString(@"Sim", nil),AMLocalizedString(@"Object", nil),AMLocalizedString(@"Info", nil),nil];
self.dataArray = arrayWithInfo;
[arrayWithInfo release];
```

To be more specific I have tableview initialized with this array. There is a possibility for user to use different localized strings, so I have to update it. By using `[tableview reloadData];` i'v got the table to update, but the values in NSArray stay the same as they were initialized in first place.

So how to make array look up at the strings once again and get their new values?

Comment: `NSArray` is immutable, you have to use `NSMutableArray`, you can modify its content in run time.

Comment: I'd also mention that your initial array doesn't appear to change because you're creating a new array every time, but in your tableview there's still a reference to "old" array.

Comment: We'd need more information about the definition of `AMLocalizedString`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using an [NSMutableArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Doing so will allow you to change its values after instantiation.

Comment: I don't need to change values in array. Just how to make the array get new value stored in AMLocalizedString(@"Status", nil)?

Comment: @Datenshi If `AMLocalizedString` is stored in the array, then you have to update a value in the array.

Answer (score 5):

Use **NSMutableArray** instead of **NSArray**

**NSMutableArray** (and all other classes with **Mutable** in the name) can be modified.

Comment: Also please check the differents between NSArray &  NSMutablearray  here https://www.google.co.in/search?q=nsarray+vs+nsmutablearray&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: I don't need to change values in array. Just how to make the array get new value stored in AMLocalizedString(@"Status", nil)? I know the difference betwen mutable and nsarray, i'm hoping there is a way to get the array to update it's values without initializing them once again.

Comment: @Datenshi There isnt a way to get the array to update like you want. Initialising the array again wont take long and is the common way of achieving what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your array doesn't need to be mutable here as the array seems to be all or nothing. You dont mention the requirement to delete some objects and not others. `NSMutableArray` isn't needed. You want to write a lazy loading getter method for the array which reinstantiates it if the array doesnt exist.

```
-(NSArray *)dataArray{
    if (_dataArray){
        return _dataArray;
    }

    _dataArray = NSArray *arrayWithInfo = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:AMLocalizedString(@"Status", nil),AMLocalizedString(@"Call", nil),AMLocalizedString(@"Location", nil),AMLocalizedString(@"Control", nil),AMLocalizedString(@"Sim", nil),AMLocalizedString(@"Object", nil),AMLocalizedString(@"Info", nil),nil];
    return _dataArray;
}
```

Then when you want to reload the tableView

```
self.dataArray = nil;
[tableView reloadData];
```

this destroys the old array, forcing it to be remade but with the new localisation.

EDIT:

The issue is the array isn't storing the statement `AMLocalizedString(@"Status", nil)` its storing the result of that statement, which is the localised string itself. There is no way to make the array re-evaluate that statement without either re-creating the whole array again or using an `NSMutableArray` and changing all the objects. The lazy loading getter method is more in the objective-c style.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `NSMutableArray`. The `NSArray` is immutable.